# python script stop execution not dead after hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am running an infinite python script in loops and catching all Exception so that script will not stop an execution.

the self.pupdate() function is fetching data from sql server and show it on a terminal, if by some reason it may be possible that it will not get data or something but it won't be stop. here is my code.

```
class live(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):

        while True:
            try:
                self.collect()
            except Exception as Conerr:
                print("run :",Conerr)
        pass
    def collect(self):
        try:
            while True:
                self.rep()
            pass
        except Exception as mai:
            print("Collect:", mai)
    def rep(self):
        try:
            self.pick_update()
        except Exception as F:
            print("REP:",F)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun = live()
    fun.start()
```

the script is not going to dead it stop executing and stuck somewhere

edit 1:

to overcome this i tried `threading.Timer` as following code ,

```
def runs():
    threading.Timer(30.0, runs).start()
    try:
        for i in range(1,10):
            pick_update()
    except Exception as yt:
        print("datafetch: ", yt)
```

but an issue with this is that if the whole cycle not complete it will start new thread and previous one is also running, is that first thread stop when it's cycle is complete? or both the thread will continue and start new every time?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: the script stop by some reason, I want to find that and solve it so that the execution will not going to stop anyhow.

Comment: Is the pick_update using an external library that can crash by itself killing the process? highly likely if it is a DLL implementation then the crash wont propagate upto the python exception handler. Also, is the thread a daemon thread in which case you might need a fun.join().

Comment: no the thread is not deamon thread, the external libraries i am using is the only pymysql which is collecting data from sql server, i checked pymysql is not crashing, i tried debugging and printing the errors it is not giving any error and just stop. no errors